disableInteractiveElementBlocking in @hello-pangea/dnd prevents onFocus on button children
We are using @hello-pangea/dnd lib and there was a need to enable disableInteractiveElementBlocking (we want to enable drag on button children). From offical docs we can see that enabling this will "...render the interactive element unusable" but I would like to know more details.
In this example we can see that onClick is triggered but onFocus is not. By commenting out disableInteractiveElementBlocking, the button will behave normally and onFocus is triggered. Any idea why?
